# Want to pull all records using 'in' statement of another table's column value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure:

## Owner

```
OwnerId - PKey  
ActionListId - FKey
```

## ActionList

```
ActionListId - PKey  
Actions - VARCHAR(8000)
```

## Action

```
ActionId - PKey
```

The format of ActionList.Actions is as follows:

```
ActionId1, ActionId2, ActionId3, ActionId4, ... ActionIdN
```

I am trying to execute this query:

```
select 
    o.*,
    a.Name
from Owner as o
join ActionList as al on al.ActionListId = o.ActionListId
join Action as a on a.ActionId in (al.Actions)
where o.OwnerId = 1;
```

But I am getting a single record back.  Why does the second join not successfully join the entirety of the array and instead only the first element?  Is there a way to get all of the Actions in the ActionList with a single query?

Comment: your  ActionList.Actions contains the more then one ActionId1 in same column?? mean in a single cell we can have more thn 1 ActionId right??   like ActionId1, ActionId2, ActionId3

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SELECT O.*,A.Name
FROM Owner AS O
     LEFT JOIN ActionList AS AL ON 
               AL.ActionListId = O.ActionListId
     LEFT JOIN Action AS A ON 
               A.ACtionID IN (SELECT ACTIONS FROM ACTIONList)
WGERE O.OwnerId = 1;
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this assuming that SELECT ACTIONS FROM ACTION is SELECT Actions FROM ActionList WHERE ActionList.ActionListId = AL.ActionListId  but i still only get 1 record back.